# Swift and Parse findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock not returning my Array

Tags: swift, parse-platform

when the compiler reach the end of findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock my coordinatesArray loses the values and the function returns a empty array. Can you help Please?
Thank you in advance

```
 func getSquadMembersCoordinates() -> Array<PFGeoPoint> {
    var coordinatesArray:[PFGeoPoint] = [PFGeoPoint]()

    if user != nil {

            let userSquad = PFUser.currentUser()?["inSquad"] as? String

            let query = PFUser.query()
            query?.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: (PFUser.currentUser()?    ["username"])!)
            query?.whereKey("inSquad", equalTo: userSquad!)
            query?.whereKey("visible", notEqualTo: false)
            query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if results?.count != 0 {

                        if let results = results {
                            for object in results {
                                coordinatesArray.append(object.objectForKey("location") as! PFGeoPoint)

                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        print("No Squad Members or not visible")
                    }
                } else {
                    print ("\(error)")
                }
            }
        } else {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SquadVC")
                self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
    }



    print("\(coordinatesArray.count)")
    return coordinatesArray

}
```

Comment: It's because the call is async. You can't return it that way. Use a closure.

Comment: Sry my friend, i'm really green in this Programing thing! How can i do that?

Comment: You need to restructure your design of this method to accept a closure as a parameter, invoke that closure with the results of findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock as a parameter. 

Try this tutorial: 
http://books.aidanf.net/learn-swift/functions

Comment: tas for the help...will study a bit more that tutorial :)

Comment: Tks all for The tips. I've finaly made it work:)

Answer (score 0):

Your code reaches the **return** line before the fetching is complete. You need something like *notification* that will update your data after fetching is done.